# pulling out text from wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the current code which 'pulls out' the blockquote from my wordpress post text and just outputs it.

html

```
<?php
     // get the content
     $block = get_the_content();

     // check and retrieve blockquote
    if(preg_match('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', $block, $matches))

    // output blockquote
    echo $matches[1];
?>
```

I am putting the blockquote on a different page than the post.

I want to do this to another paragraph in my post so I can put it on a different page as well. I don't know what other tag option I can use to do this. Whether it targets the first paragraph of the post etc.

Comment: Maybe it's a little messy but you could edit your post in text mode, to edit the actual HTML, then add some tag like `<p class="pull-out">…</p>`and use the same technique you're currently using with blockquotes.

Comment: There needs to be an identifier of some kind.

Comment: Ya I was hoping not to have to go into text mode since it's a theme and I won't have full content control.

Comment: If your html is simple regex might works fine. I would go with domxpath, with that you can query for example the first paragraph. Can you show an example for your `$block`?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. My $block just holds my blockquote text in <p> tags

Comment: I thought your content contains other html elements that you want to extract.

Comment: I just want to pull out another chunk of text that can be easily identified/chosen. So that it will appear on a different page from the entire post